# How to orderBy an array of dates(desc) while maintaining (asc) SAME day times

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to order an array of dates with their times in descending order but the times remain in ascending order with lodash.

```
const supplierDates = ["2022-02-14 10:00", "2022-02-14 08:00", "2022-02-14 09:00", "2022-02-17 19:00", "2022-02-18 18:00"
results = _.orderBy(supplierDates, suppDate => suppDate, ['desc']);
```

This sorts the array in descending order but I am interested in maintaining an ascending order for SAME day times (in this case, 14th Feb)

Comment: write a custom sort function that will split the date into date and time part and return the sort order you want. Here is an example using sortBy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846403/how-do-you-apply-a-custom-sort-to-an-array
With orderBy you may want to split the date time into two seperate fields and sort the date part desc and time part asc

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are sorting strings, while you want to sort dates.

First, order the whole dates by asc order, to maintain hours for each day.

Then use `substring` to extract ONLY the date from your strings, and then use `Date.parse` to parse to dates so you can sort them:

```js
const supplierDates = ["2022-02-14 08:00", "2022-02-14 10:00", "2022-02-14 07:00", "2022-02-17 19:00", "2022-02-18 18:00"];
const initialOrder = _.orderBy(supplierDates, suppDate => Date.parse(suppDate), ['asc']);
const results = _.orderBy(initialOrder, suppDate => Date.parse(suppDate.substring(0, 10)), ['desc']);

console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your times on the 14th are still in descending order?

Comment: @colin_dev256 thanks, didn't notice that maintain asc part. I fixed my answer

Comment: Omri my bad, it looks like I had the SAME day times in order in this example unfortunately this does not work if the SAME day times are out of order

Comment: @colin_dev256 so just order the dates in asc order before the order with substring, cmon

Comment: @colin_dev256 edited my answer

Comment: Omri ordering twice through doesn't seem like an efficient solution for a very long list of items